# shiro buji pac4j cas single sign out not work

Tags: spring-boot, single-sign-on, cas, shiro, pac4j

spring boot 2.2.5

shiro-spring-boot-web-starter 1.5.1

buji-pac4j 4.1.1

pac4j-cas 3.8.3

cas overlay template 5.3.

I start cas server in tomcat with https, and start two clients(`pac4j1` and `pac4j2`) in eclipse.

single sign on works, but `single sign out` failed.

Following are my configs:

I only added **one** `service` file under cas server which looks like:

```
{
  "@class": "org.apereo.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService",
  "serviceId": "^(http)://localhost.*",
  "name": "local",
  "id": 10000003, 
  "evaluationOrder": 1
}
```

application.yml of `pac4j1`:

```
server:
  port: 8444
  servlet:
    context-path: /pac4j1

cas:
  client-name: pac4j1Client
  server:
    url: https://localhost:8443/cas
  project:
    url: http://localhost:8444/pac4j1
```

Pac4jConfig:

```
@Configuration
public class Pac4jConfig {

    @Value("${cas.server.url}")
    private String casServerUrl;

    @Value("${cas.project.url}")
    private String projectUrl;

    @Value("${cas.client-name}")
    private String clientName;

    @Bean("authcConfig")
    public Config config(CasClient casClient, ShiroSessionStore shiroSessionStore) {

        Config config = new Config(casClient);
        config.setSessionStore(shiroSessionStore);
        return config;
    }


    @Bean
    public ShiroSessionStore shiroSessionStore(){
        return new ShiroSessionStore();
    }


    @Bean
    public CasClient casClient(CasConfiguration casConfig){

        CasClient casClient = new CasClient(casConfig);

        casClient.setCallbackUrl(projectUrl + "/callback?client_name=" + clientName);
        casClient.setName(clientName);
        return casClient;
    }

    @Bean
    public CasConfiguration casConfig(){
        final CasConfiguration configuration = new CasConfiguration();

        configuration.setLoginUrl(casServerUrl + "/login");

        configuration.setProtocol(CasProtocol.CAS20);
        configuration.setAcceptAnyProxy(true);
        configuration.setPrefixUrl(casServerUrl + "/");        

        return configuration;
    }

}
```

shiro config:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig {  

    @Value("${cas.project.url}")
    private String projectUrl;

    @Value("${cas.server.url}")
    private String casServerUrl;

    @Value("${cas.client-name}")
    private String clientName;

    @Bean("securityManager")
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(Pac4jSubjectFactory subjectFactory, CasRealm casRealm){

        DefaultWebSecurityManager manager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        manager.setRealm(casRealm);
        manager.setSubjectFactory(subjectFactory);

        return manager;
    }    

    @Bean
    public CasRealm casRealm(){

        CasRealm realm = new CasRealm();

        realm.setClientName(clientName);
        realm.setCachingEnabled(false);

        realm.setAuthenticationCachingEnabled(false);
        realm.setAuthorizationCachingEnabled(false);

        return realm;
    }

    @Bean
    public Pac4jSubjectFactory subjectFactory(){
        return new Pac4jSubjectFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<SingleSignOutFilter> singleSignOutFilter() {

        FilterRegistrationBean<SingleSignOutFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<SingleSignOutFilter>();
        bean.setName("singleSignOutFilter");

        SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
        singleSignOutFilter.setCasServerUrlPrefix(casServerUrl);
        singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);

        bean.setFilter(singleSignOutFilter);
        bean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        bean.setEnabled(true);
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> filterRegistrationBean() {

        FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy> filterRegistration = new FilterRegistrationBean<DelegatingFilterProxy>();
        filterRegistration.setFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy("shiroFilter"));

        filterRegistration.addInitParameter("targetFilterLifecycle", "true");
        filterRegistration.setEnabled(true);
        filterRegistration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        filterRegistration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD);
        return filterRegistration;
    }

    private void loadShiroFilterChain(ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean){

        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/", "securityFilter");       
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/index", "securityFilter");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/callback", "callbackFilter");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/logout", "logout");
        filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/**","anon");     
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
    }

    @Bean("shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean factory(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager, Config config) {

        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        loadShiroFilterChain(shiroFilterFactoryBean);
        Map<String, Filter> filters = new HashMap<>(3);

        SecurityFilter securityFilter = new SecurityFilter();
        securityFilter.setConfig(config);
        securityFilter.setClients(clientName);
        filters.put("securityFilter", securityFilter);

        MyCallbackFilter callbackFilter = new MyCallbackFilter();
        callbackFilter.setConfig(config);
        callbackFilter.setDefaultUrl(projectUrl);
        filters.put("callbackFilter", callbackFilter);

        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
        logoutFilter.setConfig(config);
        logoutFilter.setCentralLogout(true);
        logoutFilter.setLocalLogout(true);
        logoutFilter.setDefaultUrl(projectUrl + "/callback?client_name=" + clientName);
        filters.put("logout",logoutFilter);

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilters(filters);
        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }   

}
```

`application.properties` of `cas server` is default, and `cas server` use https(`https://localhost:8443/cas`) while `cas clients` are http(`http://localhost:8444/pac4j1`).

**Where am I wrong?**

Comment: Do client applications have their own sessions?

Comment: @leopal do u mean I need to set session explicitly in client application? where and how should i set? i defined `CasRealm` which extends `Pac4jRealm`, `MyCallbackFilter` which extends `CallbackFilter`, `MyCasClient` which extends `CasClient`, `Pac4jConfig` and `ShiroConfig`.

Comment: Well I am not familiar with your stack but I can provide some useful urls. Checkout [SLO](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html) and [SingleSignOutFilter](https://github.com/apereo/java-cas-client#configuring-single-sign-out) of `java-cas-client`. You may have to implement something similar for your case. I wish I could help you more.

Comment: @leopal thank you very much, the links you provided are very useful, I got hints from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of the link [SLO](https://apereo.github.io/cas/5.3.x/installation/Logout-Single-Signout.html) which provided by `leopal`, i know that cas server need to send log out request back to client.

Hence, i checked the log of cas server and found `INFO [org.apereo.cas.logout.DefaultLogoutManager] - <Performing logout operations for`.

so i added log for `org.apereo.cas.logout` and found that there are some classes about logout: `DefaultLogoutManager`, `DefaultSingleLogoutServiceLogoutUrlBuilder`, `DefaultSingleLogoutServiceMessageHandler` and `SimpleUrlValidator`.

when performing logout, `DefaultSingleLogoutServiceLogoutUrlBuilder.determineLogoutUrl` will get the logout url from registered service or get the original url from cas client if original url is a valid url.

So **my problem is** : i didn't define logout url in service json file and the original url from cas client is `localhost:8444` which is a invalid ipv4. As a result, cas server will not send logout request back to client.

**Solution is** : use `ip` in project url instead of `localhost` in `application.yml` of cas client:

```
cas:
  client-name: pac4j1Client
  server:
    url: https://localhost:8443/cas
  project:
    url: http://192.168.2.119:8444/pac4j1
```

another solution is set `logoutUrl` for each cas client service json file(not tried yet).